# Passing a Dictionary-like object to exec instead of dict object changes scope of enclosures

Tags: python

How come this works?

```
global_function = """
x = "Hello World"
def print_global_x():
    print(x)
print_global_x()
"""

exec(global_function, {"__builtins__": builtins})
```

but this seemingly equivalent example does not work??

```
import builtins
class TestEnvironment(dict):
    pass

global_env = TestEnvironment()
global_env['__builtins__'] = builtins
exec(global_function, global_env)
```

The second example gives an error saying that x is not defined but the first works perfectly. In effect, it seems as though the second example evaluates the code as if it were encapsulated in a class definition which is the case when two dict objects are passed to the exec function as noted in the docs.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-edb1f5a14344> in <module>()
      9 """
     10 
---> 11 exec(global_function, global_env)

<string> in <module>()

<string> in print_global_x()

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: My guess: You implement a dictionary like object that you say is your environent. This object allows for dictonery like setting but not accessing so when you run your code, the global space is attempting to store the data it your object, which it succeds in doing but then it cannot find x since there is no etattr, there is no x to be found

Comment: I don't think that is the case because if I don't define the method __getitem__, it is inherited from the parent class. I can in fact reproduce the error even if I take out both __getitem__ and __setitem__. I should do this in fact in order to create the minimum failing test.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the reason. There is apparently a bug in python 3.5.0 that was resolved python 3.5.1. I simply updated my python version and the code works. Thanks all.